# jQuery nested selector for an 'src' image URL

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the below HTML structure.

```
    <td id="123">
      ...
    <td>
        <ul>
            <li class"open"><img src="path" /></li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </td>
</tr>
<td id="125">
...
```

I want to do this:

- select `li.open` of #123 and change the class to `li.pending`
- select the `src` attribute of the `#123>li.open` image and change it to "newpath"

I tried to select them by:

```
$('#123>li.open img').attr("src");
...to add the new src

$('#123>li.open').removeClass("open").addClass("pending");
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: How about spaces? `#123 > li.open`

Comment: What was the outcome of your attempt?

Comment: First things first, you shouldn't use numeric `id` values. `IDs` should always start with a letter.

Comment: @Felix Kling: You mean `#123 li.open`? `#123>li.open` and `#123 > li.open` are the same.

Comment: @Ghazanfar in HTML5 IDs can be numbers.

Comment: @BoltClock: I wasn't sure whether Sizzle detects this. But if you say so,I believe you :) Anyway, you are right, I haven't had a look at the structure actually :-/.

Comment: Your HTML doesn't seem to be valid either, right at the end there you close a `TR` (table row) and then open a `TD`, the `TD` should be contained in a `TR`. The line you have that says "to add the new src" is actually returning the existing src, to assign a new src you'd need to do something like: `$('#123 > li.open img').attr("src", "newpath");`

Comment: @Ghazanfar - i did have the id with letters but also the same com123

Comment: @Rusty clearly the first `<td>` is just a typo.

Comment: @Alnitak I prefer to not have "typos" in my code, code does unexpected things when you have "typos".

Comment: @Rusty I doubt that the typo exists in his original code

Comment: You're assuming a lot there, do you think he printed out his code and read it off the paper while re-typing it into Stack Overflow? I'm guessing he used cut and paste, and the code he's showing is directly from his original code, but maybe I'm the only crazy person who doesn't print out my code and re-key it in when I'm asking a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `>` CSS operator enforces a direct parent-child relationship.  You have a `<td>` and `<ul>` element in between.

Remove the `>` and all should be fine.

[and per comments, for backwards compatibility don't use numbers for IDs].

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS-selector says: find `li.open` as a direct child of #123, but that's never true, because you have at least a `td`, `ul` under your `#123` element.

```
$('#123 li.open>img').attr("src");
```

is more true in the markup you have posted above. `img` is a direct child of `li.open`.